# Avoid "sbatch: error: slurm_receive_msg: Socket timed out on send/recv operation" when the scheduler is busy?

Tags: bash, sockets, scheduler, slurm

I'm running jobs on a cluster which uses [**slurm**](http://slurm.schedmd.com/) as the scheduler.

In general, what I want to do is first to submit a number of jobs to the queue, then wait till all the jobs have finished, collect data, analyze, and submit the same number of jobs to the queue again. This process is repeated a number of times.

In `single_job.sh`, I have:

```
sbatch -p partition_name -n 1 -c 1 --job-name=job_name --wrap="some_excutable"
```

In `multiple_jobs.sh`, I have:

```
for (( i=0 ; i < ${n_rounds} ; i ++ ))
do 
  #### submit jobs
  for (( j=0 ;  j < ${n_jobs} ; j ++ ))
  do
    bash single_job.sh
  done

  #### Check whether the jobs have finished, if not, wait
  njobs=`qstat -u user_name | grep ${job_name} | grep -v ' C ' | wc -l`
  count=1
  while [ $njobs -gt 0 ]
  do
    sleep 10
    njobs=`qstat -u user_name | grep ${job_name} | grep -v ' C ' | wc -l`
    count=`expr $count + 1 `
  done

 #### collect data and analyze
 python collect_data_analyze.py 

done
```

However, when the scheduler system is experiencing high load of IO burden, my program gets terminated during job submission or waiting. The following is the returned message.

```
sbatch: error: slurm_receive_msg: Socket timed out on send/recv operation
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Socket timed out on send/recv operation
```

At those moments, it takes a long time to check the job running status with `qstat`.

I was wondering is there a way to detect when the system is busy and wait for a few seconds so that to circumvent this problem ?

Comment: Do you have ``set -e`` somewhere in your script? Otherwise the script should not terminate when ``sbatch`` fails. Just make sure ``njobs`` is set to something valid when ``qstat`` fails (and you should probably use ``squeue`` rather than ``qstat``).

Comment: Also you could consider using a workflow manager see  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_workflow_system) for a list of tools.